# the variable has not been assigned.,Prefab Loses the reference after I change the value of the reference game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```csharp
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class Manager : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public  GameObject displayslider;
     public  GameObject TimeGetAngle;
     public float TimeAngle, display;
     public Text displayvaluetext, TimeAngletext;
     public static Manager instance = null;
     void Awake()
     {
         if (instance == null)
             instance = this;
         else if (instance != this)
             Destroy(gameObject);
         DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
         TimeAngle = 0;
         display = 5;
     }
     void Start()
     {
         displayslider = GameObject.Find("displayslider");
         Debug.LogError("", displayslider);
         TimeGetAngle = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Panel/TimeGetAngle");
         TimeAngletext = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Panel/TimeAngletext").GetComponent<Text>();
         displayvaluetext = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Panel/displayvaluetext").GetComponent<Text>();
         TimeAngletext.text = "" + TimeGetAngle.GetComponent<Slider>().value;
         displayvaluetext.text = "" + displayslider.GetComponent<Slider>().value;
     }
     public void TimeGetAngleselect()
     {
         TimeAngle = TimeGetAngle.GetComponent<Slider>().value;
         TimeAngletext.text = "" + TimeAngle;
     }
     public void Displayselect()
     {
         Debug.LogError("", displayslider);
         display = displayslider.GetComponent<Slider>().value;
         displayvaluetext.text = "" + display;
     }
 }
```

I have these 2 sliders in the prefab and I want to make it so that when I change the value of one of them, a text box next to it shows the value. So when a slider changes value it calls, for example, the `DisplaySelect()` method. It works fine for the preset values, however when I change the value in the slider it gives the following error:

> UnassignedReferenceException: The variable displayslider of Manager has not been assigned. You probably need to assign the displayslider variable of the Manager script in the inspector

Comment: Is your `TimeAngleText` actually at `"Canvas/Panel/TimeAngletext"`? Check capitalization. I wonder if that should be `"Canvas/Panel/TimeAngleText"`

Comment: If you're sure of all your naming as @Draco18s mentioned, then we'll need more information to help you. The code where you call `DisplaySelect()` would be a good start. Since it sounds like it works on `Start()`

Comment: Are you sure you added the callback for the changed value for `DisplaySelect()` using the prefab reference and not maybe an instance in the scene?